# Zurb menu-icon on the left hand side?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I want to put the menu-icon on the left hand side of the nav bar when it goes into mobile.  For the life of me, I can't find any documentation how to do this.  If tried putting the code in different place and using floats with custom CSS but can't get it to budge, is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
  </li>
   <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
  <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
</ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">
  <!-- Right Nav Section -->
  <ul class="left">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
.top-bar .toggle-topbar{
left:0px
}
```

Default css has `right:0px`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to tell what the css defaults are?  I have it incorporated with Rails, and all I have is the foundation_override.scss file which doesn't have that in it?

Comment: I checked foundation framework docs..http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html..here i checked the styling using inspect element..